# Best way to link excel workbooks feeding into each other for memory efficiency. Python?

Tags: python, excel, memory, filesystems, processing-efficiency

I am building a tool which displays and compares data for a non specialist audience. I have to automate the whole procedure as much as possible.
I am extracting select data from several large data sets, processing it into a format that is useful and then displaying it in a variety of ways. The problem i foresee is in the updating of the model.

I don't really want the user to have to do anything more than download the relevant files from the relevant database, re-name and save them to a location and the spreadsheet should do the rest. Then the user will be able to look at the data in a variety of ways, perform a few different analytical functions, depending on what they are looking at.  Output some graphs etc

Although some database exported files wont be that large, other data will be being pulled from very large xml or csv files (500000x50 cells) and there are several arrays working on the pulled data once it has been chopped down to the minimum possible.  So it will be necessary to open and update several files in order, so that the data in the user control panel is up to date and not all at once so that the user machine freezes.

At the moment I am building all of this just using excel formulas.

My question is how best to do the updating and feeding bit.  Perhaps some kind of controller program built with python? I don't know Python but i have other reasons to learn it.

Any advice would be very welcome.
Thanks

Comment: I'd try to build something on pandas, but from what I read it could be a task for PowerPivot as well..